# sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code

Tags: pyside, dpkg

When I run the command

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyside
```

I met the problem as follows. And I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 right now. Anyone know how to fix it? Thanks

```
dpkg: error processing python-pyside (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-configobj
 python-decorator
 python-simplegeneric
 ipython
 python-pyside.qtcore
 python-pyside.qtgui
 python-pyside.phonon
 python-pyside.qtnetwork
 python-pyside.qtdeclarative
 python-pyside.qthelp
 python-pyside.qtopengl
 python-pyside.qtscript
 python-pyside.qtsql
 python-pyside.qtsvg
 python-pyside.qttest
 python-pyside.qtxml
 python-pyside.qtuitools
 python-pyside.qtwebkit
 python-pyside

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: If it's due to an error in unmet dependencies for current installed packages (decently common), try: $ sudo apt-get -f install